# Redirect to a url for facebook like

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have a page for like grap meta tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>@Model.Title</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="@Model.Title"/> 
        <meta property="og:image" content="@Model.Image"/> 
        <meta property="og:url" content="@Model.Url"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="@Model.Description"/>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="@Model.AppId"/>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also i have a property RedirectUrl which when user click to link should redirected to.
How could I do in this page? Because this page is done just for meta tags. I want take user to another page when click to liked url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content='0; url=@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]' />
```

Or use js and document.location.